# Redux Store in React typescript Chrome browser extension

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, browser-extension

I am working on a **chrome extension using React Typescript and Fluent UI**. Now I need to implement "**Redux Store**" or anything like that into the extension but things are different from regular Redux store implementation and I couldn't find any proper resource and there's very very limited community support for this tech stack. Any leads will be helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: There is no difference between using Redux in a browser window or a chrome extension. (Source: I used it in both.)
For up-to-date resources on Redux in general, please go for the official tutorials - most other resources out there show heavily outdated ways of using Redux.
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: Hey @phry, Thanks for the info but are you sure about this because there's proper documentation for it being different here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/
Also this https://thoughtbot.com/blog/redux-for-chrome-extensions

Comment: If you want to pass data along from another window/thread, that requires extra work, but this is nothing specific to Redux, that is something specific to every interaction you will have in a WebExtension.

Comment: To get "tailored support" for that besides writing code yourself, you might want to look into libraries for multi-threading support with Redux. You will probably find more resources on WebWorkers, which use similar communication patterns. Take a look at https://dassur.ma/things/react-redux-comlink/ but keep in mind that the Redux patterns themselves in that article are quite outdated (nowadays you write reducers differently, use configureStore instead of createStore and hooks instead of connect). The gist of the article is still valid though.

Comment: okay @phry, one last question please, My extension doesn't operate on  a pop up, rather it displays it's content on  a browser tab. So in this case, will there be any changes in redux implementation? Please do answer.

Comment: Again: not from a Redux side. How you manage your inter-process communication has nothing to do with Redux. If you manage to send a message over to the other tab to do a `console.log`, you can do the same with a Redux dispatch. The only problem that might arise is that non-serializable actions like thunks or non-serializable data itself cannot be sent over. 
Generally, I'd recommend you to try and use inter-process communication without Redux and Redux without inter-process communication first and once you have a feeling for both, hook them up then.